# How can I tell Vim to close only a specific level of folds in a file?

Tags: vim

For example, how can I tell Vim to only close all level 2 folds in a file, leaving other levels open?

Edit: Let's say I have 3 levels of folds in my file.  1, 2, and 3.  I only want to close level 2 folds, leaving levels 1 and 3 open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function! FoldToTheLevel(TheLevel)    
    "set mark "f" at current position                   
    execute "normal! mf"
    "close all the folder recursively
    execute "normal! ggVGzC" 

    "open all the folder which have smaller level 
    let h=0  
    while h<a:TheLevel              
        execute "normal! ggVGzo"  
        let h+=1                                                                     
    endwhile 

    "open all the folder which have larger level           
    folddoclosed execute "normal! VzOzc" 
    "jump back and show in the middle
    execute "normal! `fzz"
endfunction   

command! -nargs=1 F call FoldToTheLevel(<f-args>)
```

add this to .vimrc

run

> :F num

to close the folder which the level is {num}

Comment: Works great!  I had to remove the comments because Vim didn't realize they were comments for some reason.  But it worked!

Comment: @NekoJiru My fault. I change it a bit, now you can stay where you are.

Answer (score 3):

You can also set `'foldlevel'` via the `[count]` on `zM`: `2zM`; this is shorter than @timrau's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`foldlevel`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'foldlevel').

```
:set foldlevel=2
```

Comment: When I do `zR` then `:set foldlevel=2` I find that all folds embedded in 2 (3 and deeper) are also closed.  I only want to close level 2.